# How can I set polymer property attribute value and passing attribute value into another polymer component property?

Tags: ajax, polymer

I have below piece of code which I am using to call http request using iron ajax with polymer so passing the value of body and last-response using polymer properties.as we can see here we have requestBody polymer property in this we are returning no of values in requestBody all values are hardcoded like start and end and name under tag.

```
        <px-vis-timeseries
                width="1000" 
                height="250"
                margin='{"top":30,"bottom":60,"left":65,"right":65}' 
                register-config='{"type":"vertical","width":200}'
                selection-type="xy" 
                chart-data="{{ltuchartData}}" 
                series-config="[[LTUseriesConfig]]"
                chart-extents='{"x":["dynamic",1619712],"y":[0,100]}' 
                event-data='[{"id":"333","time":15697128,"label":"test"}]' 
                x-axis-config='{"title":"Time"}' 
                y-axis-config='{"axis1":
                {"title":"Remaining","titleTruncation":false,"unit":"%"}}'>
              </px-vis-timeseries>
        
        
         <iron-ajax
              id="Request"
              method="POST"
              content-type="application/json"
              auto
              url="/api/series/v1/points"
              last-response="{{Data123}}"
              body="{{requestBody}}">
            </iron-ajax>
        
         Polymer({
              is: 'test-view',
        
              behaviors: [GlobalsBehaviour],
        
              properties: {
        
          uri: {
                  type: String,
                  observer: '_uriChanged'
                },
        
         requestBody:{
                  type: Object,
                  value: function() {
                    return {
                      "start": 11111,
                       "end": 123333,
                      "tags": [
                        {
                        "name" : "/asset/India/rotor",
                        }
                      ]
                    };
                  }
                }, 
        
         Data123:{
                    type: Object,
                    observer: '_formateData'
                },
        
          observers: [
              '_uriChanged(globals.uri)'
            ],
        
        
        _uriChanged: function(uri) {
          this.set('requestBody.tags.0.name', uri);
          this.$.Request.generateRequest();
        }
```

Now Below are the queries with respect to above code .

1. I want to set end attribute value (which is defined in requestBody property value )dynamically based on the uri for that I tried like :  this.set('requestBody.end', "1113444");  in _uriChanged,  But it didn't work.
2. I want to pass this end attribute value dynamically in above px-vis-timeseries polymer component's property that is:

```
chart-extents='{"x":["dynamic",1619712],"y":[0,100]}' 
event-data='[{"id":"333","time":15697128,"label":"test"}]'
```

in above properties I want to pass end attribute value like :

in chart-extents at the place of "1619712" I want to pass "end" + 2*50000
in event-data   at the place of  "15697128"  I want to pass "end" + 50000

for that also i tried like this chart-extents = '{"x":["dynamic" , {{requestBody.end}}] , ,"y":[0,100]}'

now I have set end attribute value in requestBody computed function that is (_getRequestBody) based on my requirement .Now my problem is I want to get this end attribute value in my another computed functio(n of _chartExtents that is (_getChartExtents) I want pass this end attirbute  value (which we will get from request body ) to xDynamic (which is the attribute of chartExtents)

3. As I wanted to pass uri value in name attribute which is defined in requestBody property for that I am setting like

this.set('requestBody.tags.0.name', uri);  in _urichanged callback which is working fine now my problem is while defining or declaring polymer property named as requestBody i dont want to pass any hardcoded value in name attribute for that i tried  "name": "" and "name" : this.uri,and "name" : uri ,but not able to get value.

Note: uri is coming from another polymer component and in some case its coming from global set variable.

How can I declare name attribute value without passing any hardcoded value?

Answer (score 0):

> 1. I want to set end attribute value (which is defined in requestBody property value )dynamically ...

Not a satisfactory answer, but it should work as Polymer does dirty checking. Polymer have sometimes trouble updating properties, but not in this case, so try to override dirty checking by nullifying the element first.

```
    _uriChanged: function(uri) {
      if (this.requestBody.start) {
      var clonedObj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.requestBody);
      clonedObj.tags.0.name = uri;

      this.set('requestBody', {});
      this.set('requestBody', clonedObj);
      this.$.Request.generateRequest();
    }
```

Again, this shouldn't be needed. I would most of all make requestBody a computed value instead of setting specific values,

```
   properties: {

     requestBody:{
              type: Object,
              computed: '_getRequestBody(uri)'
            },

      // Other properties, like uri

    }


    // Other javascript methods

    _getRequestBody: function(uri) {
       var defaultURI = 123333;  // I would make this a property or add a default value to 'uri'
       uri = (uri) ? uri : defaultURI;
       return {
                  "start": 11111,
                   "end": uri,   // Here's the change
                  "tags": [
                    {
                    "name" : "/asset/India/rotor",
                    }
                  ]
               };
        },
```

Note that `computed` will run no matter if the properties (`uri`, in this case) are defined or not. Sometimes, the order of the properties are important when using event handlers (*observers*) so place those last in properties.

> 2. i want to pass this end attribute value dynamically...
>
>    chart-extents='{"x":["dynamic",1619712],"y":[0,100]}'

You shouldn't pass variables like that but instead use something like        `chart-extents='[[myObject]]'`; However, for this specific solution one of the keys depends on another variable (the object `requestBody` in this case).

```
   chart-extents="[[_getChartExtents(requestBody.end)]]"

   ---

   // Other javascript methods

   _getChartExtents: function(xDynamics) {
      return {"x":["dynamic",xDynamics],"y":[0,100]};
   },
```

The `_` before the method name is just a programming habit of mine, so I can see that the methods and properties aren't used by other elements.

> 3. as i wanted to pass uri value in name attribute which is defined in requestBody property for that i am setting like this.set('requestBody.tags.0.name', uri);

Just extend answer 1.

```
    _getRequestBody: function(uri) {
       var defaultURI = 123333;  // I would make this a property or add a default value to 'uri'
       uri = (uri) ? uri : defaultURI;
       return {
                  "start": 11111,
                   "end": uri,
                  "tags": [
                    {
                    "name" : uri,  // Here's the change
                    }
                  ]
               };
        },
```

Comment: Elimaa : Thanks a lot for your help 1 and 3 point i understood and its working for me Could you please help me out for 2 point for that i am editing the question for more details.

Comment: now i have set end attribute value in requestBody computed function that is (_getRequestBody) based on my requirement . now my problem is i want to get this end attribute value in my another computed function of _chartExtents that is (_getChartExtents) i want pass this end attirbute value (which we will get from request body ) to xDynamic (which is the attribute of chartExtents)

Comment: Please help me out asap.Thanks !

Comment: I'm not on stackoverflow that often. :) I edited the second answer. Hope that helps!